# Connect Visual Studio with password protected M Access 2003 file USING Odbc

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access, passwords

I have an access password protected database.
I am using Visual Studio 2010 and ODBC.

What line of code must be added to successfuly connect to access protected file?

I am using this code:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System

Public Class DatabaseFunctions

    Shared con As OdbcConnection

    Public Shared Sub CreateConnection()

        con = New OdbcConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Dsn=XXX"
        con.Open()

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub CheckConnection()

        If con Is Nothing OrElse con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            CreateConnection()
        End If

    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CreateConnection() function code:

```
Public Shared Sub CreateConnection()
        con = New OdbcConnection
        'con.ConnectionString = "Dsn=XXX"
        con.ConnectionString = "Dsn=XXX;uid=sa;pwd=passwordRIGHT;"
        con.Open()
End Sub
```

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310985) are the way to go for several dbs